# Alias and VirtualHost difference in G-WAN

Tags: virtualhost, g-wan

What is the difference between alias and virtualhost in G-WAN?

[Here](http://gwan.com/faq#listener), it is stated that:

listener may have zero or more virtualhost, for example:

```
 / gwan / 94.230.210.136_80 / #94.230.210.136                (root host)
                            / $gwan.ch                       (virtual host)
                            / $gwan.com                      (virtual host)
                            / $trustleap.ch                  (virtual host)
                            / $trustleap.com                 (virtual host)
```

and alias assign additional domain names into existing host, contents are ignored

```
 / gwan / 94.230.210.136_80 / #94.230.210.136                (root host)
                            / #94.230.210.136:gwan.ch        (alias)
                            / #94.230.210.136:gwan.com       (alias)
                            / #94.230.210.136:trustleap.ch   (alias)
                            / #94.230.210.136:trustleap.com  (alias)
```

doesn't it the same as using symlink from root host as virtual lhost? for example

```
ln -s '#94.230.210.136' '$gwan.ch'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alias example is "correct" since visiting each of the domains results in *the same website*. You should expect your alias directories to be *empty*.

As for virtual host, the example might have been misleading. As with any other web server, "virtual host" is there so that you can host *different website* on 1 single server. So you should populate your virtual host directories with the content you desired.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between **virtual hosts** and **aliases** is simple:

- **virtual hosts** let you host *different* websites on one single IP address;
- **aliases** let you serve the *same* website from different domain names.

Hope this helps.